# Printing WebView backgrounds

Tags: cocoa, printing, webkit

in the Mac application I am currently developing the users will need to be able to print lists and reports of some of their data. I would like to use html and css so that the reports will be slightly more customizable.

I tried to do a test with the background-color css styling applied to a div and although the color would show up in the WebView nothing I tried would cause it to show up in the print preview. Is there any way to allow the background-color style to be printed?

Comment: Please ask your table question as a separate question. I've stripped it out from this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried to do a test with the background-color css styling applied to a div and although the color would show up in the WebView nothing I tried would cause it to show up in the print preview. Is there any way to allow the background-color style to be printed?

[Yes.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebPreferences_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebPreferences/setShouldPrintBackgrounds%3a)

Comment: Thanks! It works great! :) I actually also managed to figure out the solution to my other problem, so this should work well now.